# Which API: JavaFX or JMF is better for audio processing in Java?

Tags: java, api, javafx-2, jmf, audio-processing

I am doing a project in which I have to transform the audio data (which would be most probably in mp3, wav or wma format) into a waveform and also get the FFT and pitch for it along with the time in milliseconds at which the pitch change.

I am just confused whether which of these APIs is better? What are the limitations of each of these?

Answer (score 3):

JMF is ancient, clunky, and basically unmaintained.

JavaFX may or may not support what you need, but at least it's on Oracle's radar for future development.

Comment: The hour of need says ,keep using JMF coz I can't wait for that long...and Thanks for telling that JMF is unmaintained...I'll take it as a challenge to use it coz I love challenges and have started something with it

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out FMJ, which is basically an open source replacement for JMF after Sun dropped the ball with maintaining JMF:

- http://fmj-sf.net/

I haven't used it, but it does seem to have quite a few users and recently committed code which is a good sign....

Comment: I had already checked the FMJ,it seems it would not be suitable since I will need to understand that as well along with JMF...so I think JMF will be suitable as I already have started something with it ...Thanks Anyway